# Node.js simple server with Bouncy & Lactate

Tags: node.js

I setup this simple node server bellow:

#### Server.js

```
'use strict';

var lactate = require('lactate'),
    http = require('http'),
    port = 8001,
    root = '/var/www/apps';

var options = {
    root: root,
    from: '',
    not_found: root + '/404.html',
    subdirs: true,
    debug: true
};

var files = lactate.dir(root, options);

var server = new http.Server();

server.addListener('request', function(req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        files.serve('index.html', req, res);
    } else {
        files.serve(req, res);
    }
});

server.listen(port);
```

#### Route.js

```
'use strict';

var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    if (req.headers.host === 'my-app') {
        bounce(8001);
    }
    else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('no such host');
    }
});
server.listen(8000);
```

*node server.js*

*node route.js*

If a RUN just the **server.js** ALL works fine, but if i run it trough **route.js** the app keeping loop trying to download some sources(images) and never finish it.

Can i use bouncy with lactate? What am i doing wrong?

*Lactate.js source: https://github.com/Weltschmerz/Lactate*
*Bouncy.js source: https://github.com/substack/bouncy*

Thank you very much!